# Did Philip manipulate Jack?

Tags: character-analysis, ken-follett, the-pillars-of-the-earth

In *The Pillars of the Earth* following a destructive fight between Jack and Alfred, Philip concedes that the Builder's Lodge should set the punishment but made it clear that he would not tolerate both Jack and Alfred working on the Kingsbridge site any longer.

We know that he had plans for Jack to enter the monastery.

Did Philip deliberately make this ultimatum knowing the master builders would favour Alfred (the master mason) over Jack so he could recruit him as a novice?